# Remove reference of a closure when it's still undergoing a certain task in Swift

Tags: swift, closures

I've created a closure, and the value is returned after some time. During this period I'm again calling this closure with different data. The problem is, the closure response is received but the previous closure response is also received. How can I remove the reference to the first closure so I can get the response from the latest closure only?

Here's my code:

```
func getUsers() {

    self.getUsers = GetUsers()

    self.getUsers.getUsersData(latitude: Double(latitude)!, longitude: Double(longitude)!, range:range)
     { (usersArray, error) in

    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**

I've passed the current object from the closure and it seems to work fine. Here's the updated code:

```
func getUsers() {

    self.getUsers = GetUsers()

    self.getUsers.getUsersData(latitude: Double(latitude)!, longitude: Double(longitude)!, range:range)
     {[weak self] (usersArray, error, getUsersObject) in

      if let strongSelf = self {
         if strongSelf.getUsers != getUsersObject {
           return
         }
       }
    }

}
```

If the returned object from the closure doesn't match the reinitialized object, I just return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would depend upon the implementation of `getUsersData`. In general there is probably no way to cancel the callback. The best you can do is to have the callback code check some sort of flag or identifier when it runs, and do nothing if the check fails.

Example:

```
    ids.append("do this one")
    delay(2) { [weak self] in
        let id = "do this one"
        if let s = self, s.ids.contains(id) {
            print(id)
        }
    }
    ids.append("don't do this one")
    delay(2) { [weak self] in
        let id = "don't do this one"
        if let s = self, s.ids.contains(id) {
            print(id)
        }
    }
    ids.remove(at:1) // cancel this one
```

Prints "I will do this one", but does not print "don't do this one". It would have, but we cancelled it by removing it from the `ids` array.

Comment: I'm reinitialising using, self.getUsers = GetUsers(). This should remove the reference to the previous closure because the object is different now. Isn't?

Comment: No, I don't see why that would have any effect. The closure has been sent to `getUsersData` and scheduled for callback long ago. You cannot access it from here. Moreover, the closure is a closure so whatever environment it captured remains captured.

Comment: I've updated my answer. This is working. But is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: Well, that's essentially what I said to do: match against something in the current state. Very nice. The only problem is that you are capturing `self`, which risks a memory leak. You'll notice I was careful not to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've again updated my answer. Is this how it should be done?

Comment: Yes! That should be safe.